# Referring to cell using Range("cell content") gives error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I'm new here and im novice in VBA coding and fried told me that if i have problems with my code that StackOverflow is best site for help.

I'm getting

> runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed

error is occurring on  this line

```
Set rng = ws.Range("Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)").Select
```

I thought that i can reference to ranges by any value they contain. So please where i am making mistake? And no it is not named range i just wanted to select it based on its value which is "Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)"

```
Option Explicit

Sub sum_funkcie()

Dim MonthYear As String
Dim KGL As Double
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Graf Neg. Loss")
Set rng = ws.Range("Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)").Select


MonthYear = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
KGL = ws.Range("Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)").End(xlDown)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference a range by its value, you can define a name for a range and use that named range for your reference.

What you will need to do is search for the value then select the cell:

Replace:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)").Select
```

With:

```
Dim csel As Range
  With Worksheets("Graf Neg. Loss").Cells ' 
     Set csel = .Find("Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not csel Is Nothing Then
            csel.Select
        End If
  End With
```

Comment: Unrelated: Totally unrelated: I saw that your flagged for "editing" on the triage queue for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255136/error-unable-to-install-the-extension-corrupted-meta-xml-file-in-plesk ... simply: wrong decision. This question requires the OP to add his code [mcve]. Only the OP should do such things. So please keep in mind: only triage for editing when other people can edit the question. Anything that requires the owner to improve the content, should not go "edit"!

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the suffixed `.Select`, and note that the parameter to `Range` needs to be a *named range* (or cell reference): you can't reference by cell *contents*.

```
Set rng = ws.Range("Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)")
```

`ws.Range` returns a reference to a `Range` anyway, and VBA that messes around with the user selections can be quite annoying for the user.

If this still results in an error, check you've spelt the range name correctly. And is the scope of that range global or local to that worksheet? It should be the latter.

Comment: thanks but it is not working. I deleted  `. select`  but same error is occuring

Comment: it is same error _"runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed"_, it is not a named range  _"Kumulatív Gross Loss (mio)"_ is a simple value in cell *H2*

Comment: @TooMachoBA For it to work in that syntax, it MUST be a named range.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  Yeah i know already and was able to make it work with named range but thx for your comment :)